# Calling a javascript function inside Xamarin.Forms webview

Tags: javascript, url, webview, xamarin.forms, eval

I have a WebView control where the source is a website address.How can I add javascript to the webview to remove an element?
Here is my code which is not working:

```
     <WebView Source="http://www.classroomdj.com/courses/22/playlists"                   x:Name="webView"
                HeightRequest="1000"
                WidthRequest="1000"   />

///after initialize component
webView.Eval("document.getElementsByClassName('element')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden'")
```

Comment: This isn't working in a normal browser as well. Are you sure the name is `'element'`?

Comment: its an element's class name, if you put the class name instead of element of specific div the javascript will hide it.